# No me esta imprimiendo la cadena de caracteres

Tags: c

Estoy con un proyecto de recrear funciones de C para aprender y estoy con la funcion memset la cual al intentar recrear su funcionamiento me da el siguiente error

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
[1]    3679 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Este es el codigo y mi main

```
#include <stdio.h>

void    *ft_memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)
{
    char *ptr;

    ptr = str;
    while (n)
    {
        *(ptr++) = (unsigned char)c;
        n--;
    }
    return (str);
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "";
    ft_memset(str, 4, 10);

    printf("%s", str);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te presento un array de tamaño fijo de longitud 1. Su contenido se limita a un caracter nulo:

```
char str[] = "";
```

Y aquí intentas modificar 10 posiciones del mismo:

```
ft_memset(str, 4, 10);
```

Es como pretender que un coche entre en un tupper...

Tienes que crear un array de tamaño suficiente para que la función cumpla su cometido:

```
char str[11] = "";
```

Tienes que resevar espacio para 11 caracteres porque no hay que olvidar que en C, las cadenas de caracteres terminan **siempre** con `'\0'`.

Arreglamos esto y... sorpresa!!! el programa sigue sin mostrar nada!!!

Eso es porque, atendiendo a una tabla ASCII, el caracter 4 **no es imprimible**. Reemplaza `4` por `'4'` y vuelve a probar:

```
ft_memset(str, '4', 10);
```

**Nota final** Para terminar, el error que te aparece se produce porque los arrays de tamaño fijo se alojan en la pila del programa... y al intentar escribir varias posiciones fuera del array estás escribiendo fuera de los límites de dicha pila... eso lo detecta el sistema operativo y mata tu programa para que no corrompa memoria que no le pertenece.

> Seria posible que no tenga que especificar el tamaño del string? Es decir yo lo que busco es un string el cual no se en un principio su tamaño y quiero que me aloje el espacio segun lo necesite

En C no hay procesos automáticos que cumplan tus expectativas.

Habría, no obstante, una posible solución y pasa por usar punteros y memoria dinámica.

Lo primero sería cambiar `str` para que fuese un puntero. Es importantísimo inicializarlo a `0` o a `NULL`, que es lo mismo:

```
char * str = NULL;
```

para redimensionar la memoria gestionada tenemos que usar `realloc`:

```
char* ptr = realloc(str, 1 * sizeof(char)); // Espacio para un char
if( ptr == NULL )
{
  // Error al reservar la memoria

  free(str); // como str apunta a NULL, no hará nada

  exit(1);
}

str = ptr;
ptr = realloc(str, 10 * sizeof(char)); // Espacio para 10 char (string de 9 caracteres)
if( ptr == NULL )
{
  // Error al reservar la memoria

  free(str); // liberamos la memoria reservada previamente

  exit(1);
}
```

Es importante, como ves, no sobreescribir `str` directamente. Hay que comprobar que `realloc` ha finalizado con éxito porque si no perdemos la capacidad para recuperar la memoria reservada anteriormente.

El problema que tiene `realloc` es que no es algo automático y tampoco es algo que debas meter en tu función `ft_memset` ya que la función original **no hace** malabares con la memoria. La versión original asume que sabe lo que estás haciendo y que te cuidas de no escribir fuera de los límites del array.

Comment: Seria posible que no tenga que especificar el tamaño del string? Es decir yo lo que busco es un string el cual no se en un principio su tamaño y quiero que me aloje el espacio segun lo necesite

Comment: Perfecto, lo que queria hacer yo era ir un paso mas alla de memset a secas para intentar automatizarlo y que si se quiere modificar solo sea la menor cantidad de veces posible.

Comment: @Black171 yo no haría eso. Si lo haces, no podrás llamar a tu función usando arrays sino que obligarás a usar siempre punteros y memoria dinámica

Comment: @Black171 piensa que si la librería estándar no te da una facilidad suele ser por alguna razón

Comment: Buen tip, creo que me limitare a dejar la funcion como la original, crei que seria mas bueno automatizarlo y dejarlo lo mas usable posible

Comment: @Black171 Otra opción es crear tu propia biblioteca para manejar strings sin especificar un tamaño fijo.

Answer (score 1):

un error no grave pero si malo en terminos de programacion es copiar un puntero void a char recuerda que son diferentes tipos por lo tanto debes hacer un cast explicito, otro error es que intentas modificar 10 posiciones en un array de longitd 1 por lo tanto ocurre un desbordamiento de buffer, aveces aparece como (sig fault) o (core dump) modifique tu codigo un poco para que funcione revisalo y analiza las diferencias. Espero y te sirva este ejemplo. Buena suerte

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void *ft_memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr =(char *)str;   // Es necesario hacer un cast explicito ya que son diferentes tipos de dato

    size_t inicio = 0;
    while (inicio < n)
    {
        //*(ptr++) = (unsigned char)c;
        *ptr = (char) c;
        inicio++;
        ptr++;
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = " esta es una cadena de ejemplo";
    size_t longitud = 10;
    printf("%s\n", str);
    ft_memset(str, 'c', longitud);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: La etiqueta de la pregunta es sobre C y en C no necesitas hacer un casting explicito cuando usas un puntero genérico. Es decir, si compilas esta instrucción: `ptr = str; `, no dará ningún error de compilación, pero si lo haces en C++ si necesitaras hacer el casteo. En tu caso veo que has usado un compilador de C++ y por eso te dio ese error.

Comment: si tienes razon no habia notado que lo estaba pidiendo en c

Comment: @BayronJonathanVazquez Podrias editar tu respuesta a C? No se de c++ y considero que se podria hacer de esta manera el memset tambien